# EndToEndMetrics on pooled db connections: isolated or not?

Tags: java, database-connection, datasource

A dba in my office proposed the following to audit db access (oracle):

Put the current logged in user in my application as a property on the db connection (java.sql.Connection).

```java
public class ClientInfoProvider { 
    void enrichConnection(Connection connection, String userName)  throws SQLException  {
        OracleConnection oConn = (OracleConnection) connection;
            String[] metrics = new String[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_STATE_INDEX_MAX];
            metrics[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_CLIENTID_INDEX] = userName;
            oConn.setEndToEndMetrics(metrics, (short) 0);
    }
}

public class AuditableDataSource implements DataSource {
...
    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        clientInfoProvider.enrichConnection(connection, loggedInUserString);
        return connection;
    }

...
}
```

My main concern is that connections are pooled. Wil users not end up using the same connection? The last user which changes the properties of the connection might influence the other users that are already using this connection. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: `public class X extends X`? That's a new one...

Comment: Sorry fge, error on my part, changed accordingly. Issue still holds.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - what property is being modified based on the user? Is the loggedInUserString same as the username attribute for the datasource connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Spring jdbc datasource, a jdbc connection lives only long enough to execute it's query. Once the query is executed and the resultset has been closed, the connection will also be closed and released to the pool to be used for another query.